# How to find the volume of cross sections of a circle

Tags: calculus

Use calculus to find the volume of the following solid S:

The base of $S$ is a circular disk with radius $r$. Parallel cross-sections perpendicular to the base are isosceles triangles with height $h$ and unequal side in the base.

Knowing that each triangle slice is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{r^2-x^2} \cdot h$, I just have to integrate that function from $-r$ to $r$ and multiply that result by $2$ since my integral only finds the top semicircle. How am I supposed to integrate this especially when I am given variables instead of numbers?

Comment: The conventional way to find $\int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx$ is to make the trig substitution $x=r\sin\theta$. We end up integrating $r^2\cos^2 x$, and use the double angle formula $\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$. A bit messy! The easy way is to note that $\int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx$ is the area of the half-circle.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In title you mean " volume of solid with given cross sections".